# c#: Populate combobox at design time

Tags: c#, combobox, populate, design-time

I already know how to populate a combobox using c# code but, Is there a way to populate a combobox at design time using the designer/properties ?

Comment: Yes. What sort of combobox? WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET?

Comment: If it's Forms.COmboBox, there is Items collection in Properties tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Properties explorer of combo box or Press F4 find the Items property. Refer to the image below.[image: combobox properties]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [Dans Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729310/395659):

```
var items = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Mpost", "Posted"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Call", "Calling"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RScan", "Re-Scan"));

myComboBox.DataSource = items;
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
```